# Hana SQL script - is there a way to replace multiple CASE WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN X ELSE Y

Tags: sql, hana

Is there a way to replace multiple CASE WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN X ELSE Y?
See attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FegwE.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20db6dd7751910149105978452f92bbd.html

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 2):

You can use both coalesce and ifnull in this scenario as below :

1. Coalesce :
   select coalesce(<**column_name**>,<**value in case of null**>) from XYZ;
2. Ifnull :
   Select ifnull(<**column_name**>,<**value in case of null**> ) from XYZ;

Answer (score 0):

I guess `ifnull` is the thing you are looking for:
https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-sql-reference-guide/ifnull-function-miscellaneous

Answer (score 0):

The closest to what you seem to aim is probably `coalesce()`, which is a function that returns the first non-NULL of its arguments :

```sql
SELECT coalesce(NULL, 'red');
red
```

```sql
SELECT coalesce('green', 'red')
green
```